# Handling localhost error Method not allowed and Not found in python

Tags: python, localhost, web.py

I try to execute the most easy code and yet i keep getting errors on my local host like "Method not allowed" or "Not found"

It is making the whole learning process frustrating

```py
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'arena'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())


class arena:
    def Get(self):
        return "arena"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: post the error you getting

Comment: the error i am getting is not found

Comment: 127.0.0.1:49478 - - [08/Apr/2020 18:35:54] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 405 Method Not Allowed
127.0.0.1:49478 - - [08/Apr/2020 18:35:57] "HTTP/1.1 GET /" - 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: you have used 'Get' try using  'GET'  it ll start working .

Comment: i sent you a request on linkedin please can we talk?

Comment: Yes it did work thanks Man

Comment: @sam thanks for your help. This is my mail nnaemekapatokolo@gmail.com i will like to engage you please.